# My BehaviorSubject not working as expected and does not seem to call "next"

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a Clip Service:

```
export class ClipService {

    allClips: Clip[] = [];
    private clips = new BehaviorSubject<Clip[]>(null);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.loadClips();
    }

    private fetchClips(body?: string): Observable<Clip[]> {
        let url = myurl/clips;
        try {
            return this.http.get<Clip[]>(url);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error fetching clips: ' + e);
        }
        
    }

    loadClips(): void {
        this.fetchclips().subscribe(allClips => this.allClips = allClips);
        this.setClips(this.allClips);
    }

    getClips(): Observable<Clip[]> {
        return this.clips.asObservable();
    }
}
```

and a ClipComponent.ts where I cosume the service like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clipService.getClips().subscribe(clips => {
        this.allClips = clips;
        this.clips = this.allClips;

        console.log(this.clips);
        this.populateFilters(this.clips);
    });
}
```

Even though a call to the API is triggered and there are around 200 clips returned, the console.log in the component always logs an empty array.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I updated the code and cut out everything that is not needed here. I don't know how to create a "live" example, since I consume a DB. Is there a way of mocking that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The variable `this.allClips` is assigned asynchronously in the service. So any statements that directly depend on it must be inside the subscription. By the time you're doing `this.setClips(this.allClips);` it still holds the previous value or `undefined`.

```js
loadClips(): void {
  this.fetchclips().subscribe(allClips => {
    this.allClips = allClips;
    this.setClips(this.allClips);
  });
}
```

You could find more info about asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

2. If you're initializing the `BehaviourSubject` with `null`, you could as well use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1. It serves the same purpose as the `BehaviorSubject` except it doesn't need a default value (so you don't have to deal with the initial `null`) and it doesn't have the `BehaviorSubject`'s synchronous `getValue()` function.

```js
private clips = new ReplaySubject<Clip[]>(1);
```